# how to format an xml file generated from a datagridview in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a datagridview with data which I would like to save as an XML file. Im only using windows forms the last two weeks so my experience is limited. I have managed to save the file but i want to know how to save it formatted like my example below. I would be grateful for any help

```
//This is what im getting
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <itemstable>
    <ProcessName>batchmnt.exe</ProcessName>
    <ProcessPID>DDD</ProcessPID>
    <ProcessFileName>mark</ProcessFileName>
    <Operation>WriteFile</Operation>
    <ProcessLength>3</ProcessLength>
    <ProcessPath>mark</ProcessPath>
    <ProcessKey>batchmnt.exe|DDD|mark|WriteFile</ProcessKey>
  </itemstable>
<DocumentElement>

//This is what im looking for
<Msg Date ="" Time="">
    <Layer Name="Core">
        <SourceLayer Name="PMC">
        <Message ProcessName=""
                 PID =""
                 FileName=""
                 Operation=""
                 Length=""
                 Path="">                
        </Message>
    </Layer>
</Msg>

//And this is my code    
private void SaveXML()
        {
            string filename = "";
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "XML (*.xml)|*.xml",
                FileName = ""
            };
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = sfd.FileName;
                Deleteifexists(filename);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("itemstable");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name, typeof(System.String));
                }

                DataRow myrow;
                int icols = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    myrow = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
                    {

                        myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
                }

                dt.WriteXml(filename);
            }


        }
```

Comment: there is no similarity between current xml and expected xml. how do you expect DataTable to guess what you want?

Comment: OOP way to do this - will be to create a Hierarchy of objects and populate it using the DataGrid values. Then XmlSerialize.

Comment: Yes i know they are not similar outputs. Im looking to have the output like i have shown, not whats currentyl ouput

Comment: Set [DataColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties. In particular `ColumnName`, `ColumnMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable.WriteXML will also additionally take in an XMLSchema.

If you scroll to the botton of this link here is an example of how the schema is used: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx